# How to display multiple rows, as one row, without using a MAX aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, merge

I have a table that contains A LOT of rows, with several identifiers that are relevant in the big picture, but in my current task, only  3 columns are important:

```
SiteIdentifier | SysTm | Signalet
```

SiteIdentifier is a number, SysTm is DateTime and Signalet is a text field.
Ex data:

```
587451 | 2021-03-01 00:00:00 | Left
587451 | 2021-03-04 07:12:17 | Joined
214537 | 2021-03-05 02:13:03 | Left
587451 | 2021-03-04 12:12:12 | Left
214537 | 2021-03-05 07:13:00 | Joined
587451 | 2021-03-08 01:04:07 | Joined
```

Here's what I want to achieve:
**I want to create a query that can display:**

```
SiteIdentifier | SysTm of last Signalet Left | SysTm of last Signalet Joined | DATEDIFF(hour, ...  between last Left and Joined
```

In the case of the lines of example data, a result would be:
**It is important that I get EVERY instance of EVERY SiteIdentifier**

```
587451 | 2021-03-01 00:00:00 | 2021-03-04 07:12:17 | 79
214537 | 2021-03-05 02:13:03 | 2021-03-05 07:13:00 | 5
587451 | 2021-03-04 12:12:12 | 2021-03-08 01:04:07 | 84
```

(*Each SiteIdentifier can be represented NUMEROUS times*)

These rows are all contained in one table, which is what is tripping me up...

I asked this question earlier, and was given this query:

```
SELECT SiteIdentifier,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Signalet = 'Left' THEN SysTM END) as left_tm,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Signalet = 'Joined' THEN SysTM END) as Joined_tm,
       DATAEDIFF(hour,
                 MAX(CASE WHEN Signalet = 'Left' THEN SysTM END),
                 MAX(CASE WHEN Signalet = 'Joined' THEN SysTM END)
                ) as time_diff
FROM Table
WHERE Signalet IN ( 'Left', 'Joined')
GROUP BY SiteIdentifier
ORDER BY SiteIdentifier
```

This query gave me the most recent "row" of EACH SiteIdentifier, but not all results.
*I am trying to get the result to be, as I wrote above, a SiteIdentifier can be represented multiple times.*

Comment: I suggest providing DDL+DML for your sample data to make it easier for us to assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a row number across the `SiteIdentifier` for each of `Signalet` "Left" and "Joined", and then join on the matching row you get the desired results.

Note: Added a clunky second left join to handle the case when the first row isn't a 'left' record.

```
declare @Test table (SiteIdentifier int, SysTm datetime2(0), Signalet varchar(21));

insert into @Test (SiteIdentifier, SysTm, Signalet)
values
(587451, '2021-03-01 00:00:00', 'Left'),
(587451, '2021-03-04 07:12:17', 'Joined'),
(214537, '2021-03-05 02:13:03', 'Left'),
(587451, '2021-03-04 12:12:12', 'Left'),
(214537, '2021-03-05 07:13:00', 'Joined'),
(587451, '2021-03-08 01:04:07', 'Joined');

with cte as (
    select *
      , row_number() over (partition by SiteIdentifier, Signalet order by SysTm) rn
    from @Test
)
select C1.SiteIdentifier, C1.SysTm, coalesce(C2.SysTm, C3.SysTm), datediff(hour, C1.SysTm, coalesce(C2.SysTm, C3.SysTm))
from cte C1
left join cte C2 on C2.SiteIdentifier = C1.SiteIdentifier and C2.Signalet = 'Joined' and C2.rn = C1.rn and C2.SysTm > C1.SysTm
left join cte C3 on C3.SiteIdentifier = C1.SiteIdentifier and C3.Signalet = 'Joined' and C3.rn = C1.rn + 1 and C3.SysTm > C1.SysTm and C2.rn is null
where C1.Signalet = 'Left'
order by C1.SysTm asc;
```

Returns:

| SiteIdentifier | SysTm (Left) | SysTm (Joined) | Diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 587451 | 2021-03-01 00:00:00 | 2021-03-04 07:12:17 | 79 |
| 587451 | 2021-03-04 12:12:12 | 2021-03-08 01:04:07 | 85 |
| 214537 | 2021-03-05 02:13:03 | 2021-03-05 07:13:00 | 5 |

Note if you add DDL+DML as I have done to your questions you make it much easier for people to assist.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! I didn't know about adding DDL and DML, but I do now, and I will be sure to do so in the future! I don't have access to test this on the actual live DB at the moment, but I tested on a fiddle, and it sure looks like it will return everything I am trying to achieve. I will be sure to accept your answer once I've had a chance to test it live.

Comment: I just had a chance to test this on the live data, and as long as the first Signalet is a 'Left', it seems to work, but when a 'Joined' is found before the first 'Left', there is an issue... I didn't think of that in the specifications, but there are times where a 'Joined' can be the first Signalet found for a SiteIdentifier. Is there a way to solve / work around that?

Comment: @Geir please update your question with another data set and expected results to illustrate.

Comment: Hi @[Dale K] Sorry, I've been so busy, I haven't had a chance to follow up... I am finding that when I use example data, in a fiddle, everything works like a charm, but when I apply it to the live data, I get the Left Signalet, but Joined Signalet and DATEDIFF, returns NULL. Even using the updated C3 version which takes care of a Joined preceding the Left Signalet. I'll just accept the answer, but if you have an idea, I'd be glad to hear it! PS! The live data of the SiteIdentifier I'm testing with, spans back to Oct. 2016 and first Signalet is a Joined.

Comment: I just discovered in the live database, what is probably causing the error... Sometimes, both Signalet Left and Signalet Joined can be represented twice. Like two Joined following each other with a timestamp of a few milliseconds apart. That will cause the CTE to have two Joined (or Left) in rows after another, and not Joined, Left, Joined, Left, etc. It could be Joined, Joined, Left, Joined, Left, Left, etc...

Comment: You really need a new question with a [mre] that includes all the edge cases you have found.

Comment: @[Dale K] I'm working on a new question now, with DDL so it should be easier to see what I'm finding. Thank you so much for your help so far! :)