# Conditional aggregation query giving result for individual record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following tables exactly as follows

**Order**

| OrderID | UserID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 13 |
| 4 | 7 |

**RentalItems**

| RentalItemsID | ItemID | ReturnTypeID | OrderID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 | 5 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 | 2 |
| 4 | 5 | 5 | 2 |
| 5 | 10 | 4 | 3 |
| 6 | 11 | 4 | 4 |
| 7 | 14 | 5 | 4 |

> ReturnTypeID **5**: Defect Return

> ReturnTypeID **4**: Normal Return

```
select [order].UserID,
    (
        select avg(case when ReturnTypeID = 5 then 1.0 else 0 end) as DefectedRate
        from RentalItems 
        where RentalItems.OrderID = [Order].OrderID 
    ) as DefectedReturnRate
from [Order] 
where OrderID in (select OrderID from RentalItems where ReturnTypeID=5)
```

**Current Output**: Calculated as: DefetedReturnByUserPerOrder/AllReturnsByUserPerOrder

| UserID | DefectReturnRate | Showing Calculation, (Not incl. in output) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 1.00 | Order1: 1/1 - Contained 1 item and it was defected returned |
| 1 | 0.66 | Order2: 2/3 - Contained 3 items and 2 were defected returned |
| 7 | 0.50 | Order4: 1/2 - Contained 2 items and 1 was defected returned |

as you can see, it is calculating DefetecedReturnRate per each Order and not total Items rented by user across ALL Orders

**Desired Output:** TotalDefetedReturnByUserForALLOrders/AllReturnsByUserForAllOrders

| UserID | DefectReturnRate | Showing Calculation, (Not incl. in output) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 0.66 | Order1&4: 2/3 - Total Rented items by User 7 were 3 and 2 were defected Returns |
| 1 | 0.66 | Order2: 2/3 - Contained 3 items and 2 were defected returned |

I think this will be my last question so any help will be greatly appreciated. I can provide DML+DDL data but I'm not sure how to. I tried to generate scripts but it was only generating tables and not data. but the tables and data is exactly as I have entered in tables above.

Comment: You create DDL+DML by *writing* create temp table statements (or table variable statements) and *writing* insert statements with a small sample of data :) You can see it on many questions and answers on this site. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66579175/1127428)

Comment: Ohh.. I see.  I thought it was something that can be generated. Thank you!.

Comment: You can generate it from SSMS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982568/what-is-the-best-way-to-auto-generate-insert-statements-for-a-sql-server-table

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface, I just tried it and it works!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

```
SELECT UserID, AVG(case when ReturnTypeID = 5 then 1.0 else 0 end) as DefectedRate
FROM orders 
JOIN dbo.RentalItems AS ri
   ON ri.OrderID = orders.OrderID
WHERE ri.OrderID in (select OrderID from RentalItems where ReturnTypeID = 5)
GROUP BY UserID
```

Comment: Ahh.. I see what you did. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You can also write it slightly differently without the need for hitting RentalItems twice.

This way yields 5 logical reads vs 12 logical reads, so in the real world will be more performant, should that matter for your circumstances.

```
select distinct userid, Returned
from (
    select o.userid,  Sum (case when ReturnTypeId=5 then 1.0 end) over( partition by userid) / Count(*) over(partition by userid)  Returned
    from Orders o
    join RentalItems ri on ri.orderid=o.orderid
)s
where returned is not null
```

Comment: it does not matter in my case but I see your approach aswell.  I wish I could select both answers as reply but thank you!